# if we have 2 independent variables w correlation can we still use them in OLS

Tags: least-squares, statsmodels

I've read from some resources that one of the assumptions in ols is that the predictor variables do not have a correlation. Is this because correlation => linear dependency? Which I know we cant have because in the proof for OLS we take the inverse of our matrix of predictor variables.

If they do should we cut one of them out?

And if we were to add it to our model, and the R^2 increases does this imply that its falsely doing so due to the correlation?

Or are we actually improving the variance we can predict with our model?

Comment: If correlated predictors would invalidate OLS, then there wouldn't be any point in doing a multiple linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never a good idea to remove data. (Although if 2 independent variables are *exactly* linearly dependent then one must be removed, but you're not then losing any information.)

Correlated independent variables do pose problems with the ability of a model developed on a particular data sample to extend to the population as a whole. These problems and ways to deal with them are discussed extensively on this site. Try following tags like `multicollinearity`, `multiple-regression` and `regularization` on Cross Validated, and study resources like [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf), in particular chapters 3, 5 and 6.